# Pandas groupby/pivot table for counting values in 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame like so

```
week  player_a  player_b
 1      True      True
 1      True     False
 1     False     False
 2     False      True
 2     False     False
 2      True     False
```

and I would like to count the number of True and False for each player by week, but I cannot seem to finagle this into a convenient pandas groupby or pivot table operation. The desired result would look like:

```
week            True  False
      player
 1   player_a     2     1
     player_b     1     2
 2   player_a     1     2
     player_b     1     2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) first and then count [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df1 = df.melt('week', var_name='player')

df = pd.crosstab([df1['week'], df1['player']], df1['value'])
```

Or use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df = df1.pivot_table(index=['week', 'player'], columns='value', fill_value=0, aggfunc='size')
```

Or aggregate counts by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = df1.groupby(['week', 'player', 'value']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

---

```
print (df)
value          False  True 
week player                
1    player_a      1      2
     player_b      2      1
2    player_a      2      1
     player_b      2      1
```

And solution with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html),  [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and `unstack`:

```
df = df.set_index('week').stack().groupby(level=[0,1]).value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
               False  True 
week                       
1    player_a      1      2
     player_b      2      1
2    player_a      2      1
     player_b      2      1
```

Answer (score 6):

Use pandas pivot_table function and aggregate by size.

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['week','player'], columns='value', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
```